# "Sleep" function and suspend count

Tags: c++, time, sleep

I want to find out whether or not a certain process is sleeping or not (C++/Windows).
I'm trying to use the suspend count to do so and suspending to process before the check for
profiling processes.

I'm doing something like this:

```
SuspendThread(threadHandle);

... Do Some Stuff ...

int suspended = ResumeThread(threadHandle);
if (suspended > 1)
    m_isSleeping = true;
```

According to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
If a process is suspended, "ResumeThread" returns a value > 0.
In my case, the process is a sleeping process, so I'd expect that the suspend count would be [My Call To SuspendThread] + [The "Sleep" method within the process] = 2
but I keep getting:  ResumeThread(threadHandle) == 1

Does anybody know why it happens?
thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to know how to tell if a process is sleeping or do you want to know why the return value isn't what you expect?

Comment: I'd like to know how to tell if a process is sleeping. (I'd also like to know why I'm getting this result, but it's not the main issue :))

Comment: You made an assumption that a sleeping thread is a suspended thread and that suspend count should increase when you put a thread to sleep. This is an incorrect assumption. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Although you might have *meant* to ask how to detect that a thread is sleeping, that's not what you really asked. You merely asked why you're getting an unexpected result from `ResumeThread`. To find out how to detect a sleeping thread, I suggest you post a new question. You've already gotten answers to this question, so it would be wrong to edit it to ask something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing threads and processes.  `ResumeThread` and `SuspendThread` do not operate on *process* handles, they operate on *thread* handles.  Also, `Sleep` does not change the suspend count of a process, only `ResumeThread` and `SuspendThread` change that.  If you're trying to detect if a thread is currently in a `Sleep` call, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Idov: You can't.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006691/how-to-check-if-a-win32-thread-is-running-or-in-suspended-state .

Comment: @Idov: the question is *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Why? and what does your link has to do with it?
@ybungalobill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587065/measuring-time-of-a-profiled-sleep-function

Comment: @Idov: A thread can be in 3 states: Running, ready, or waiting.  A running thread is one that is actually running on a CPU.  A ready thread is one that is capable of running but has not yet been scheduled to run on a CPU.  A waiting thread is a thread that cannot run because it is waiting for something: it's sleeping, it's blocked on I/O or a synchronization object, etc.  The runnable states are running and ready.

Comment: OK! then if I get the thread's state and it's waiting, it may be sleeping? If so, it's good enough for me. It's even better :)

Answer (score 2):

A thread in `Sleep` isn't suspended, hence the return value of 1

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what others said, your `SuspendThread` call is not guaranteed to suspend thread immediately, it can be running for a time, and you can actually call `ResumeThread` while thread is still running (see details: http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/WRK/2009/01/what-does-suspendthread-really-do/)