# How does GCC's '-pg' flag work in relation to profilers?

Tags: gcc, compilation, gprof, compiler-flags

I'm trying to understand how the `-pg` (or `-p`) flag works when compiling C code with GCC.

The official GCC documentation [only states](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-pg-540):

> `-pg`
> Generate extra code to write profile information suitable for the analysis program gprof. You must use this option when compiling the source files you want data about, and you must also use it when linking.

This really interests me, as I'm doing a small research on profilers. I'm trying to pick the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Compiling with [-pg](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-pg) instruments your code, so that [Gprof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof) reports detailed information. See [gprof's manual, 9.1 Implementation of Profiling](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Implementation.html):

> Profiling works by changing how every function in your program is compiled so that when it is called, it will stash away some information about where it was called from. From this, the profiler can figure out what function called it, and can count how many times it was called. This change is made by the compiler when your program is compiled with the `-pg` option, which causes every function to call `mcount` (or `_mcount`, or `__mcount`, depending on the OS and compiler) as one of its first operations.
>
> The `mcount` routine, included in the profiling library, is responsible for recording in an in-memory call graph table both its parent routine (the child) and its parent's parent. This is typically done by examining the stack frame to find both the address of the child, and the return address in the original parent. Since this is a very machine-dependent operation, `mcount` itself is typically a short assembly-language stub routine that extracts the required information, and then calls `__mcount_internal` (a normal C function) with two arguments—`frompc` and `selfpc`. `__mcount_internal` is responsible for maintaining the in-memory call graph, which records `frompc`, `selfpc`, and the number of times each of these call arcs was traversed.
>
> ...

Please note that with such an instrumenting profiler, you're profiling the same code you would compile in release without profiling instrumentation. There is an overhead associated with the instrumentation code itself. Also, the instrumentation code may alter instruction and data cache usage.

Contrary to an instrumenting profiler, a sampling profiler like [Intel VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) works on noninstrumented code by looking at the target program's program counter at regular intervals using operating system interrupts. It can also query special CPU registers to give you even more insight of what's going on.

See also [Profilers Instrumenting Vs Sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671003/profilers-instrumenting-vs-sampling).

Answer (score 10):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981121/how-exactly-does-gprof-work/5046039#5046039) gives a brief explanation of how gprof works.

[This link](http://archive.today/9r927) gives an extensive critique of it.
(Check my answer to the archived question.)

Comment: I have been doing pretty much all of my speed profiling just using break and backtrace in gdb since reading those.

Comment: @David: I get lots of arguments about it, but I did *[this example](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1870/1262)* with it. 700x speedup. I don't say pausing is pretty, but nobody's gotten a result like that any other way, that I know of.

Comment: It would need to be more than a link-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

From *"[Measuring Function Duration with Ftrace](https://elinux.org/images/0/0c/Bird-LS-2009-Measuring-function-duration-with-ftrace.pdf)"*:

> Instrumentation comes in two main
> forms—explicitly declared tracepoints, and implicit tracepoints.
>
> Explicit tracepoints consist of developer defined
> declarations which specify the location of the
> tracepoint, and additional information about what data
> should be collected at a particular trace site. Implicit
> tracepoints are placed into the code automatically by the compiler, either due to compiler flags or by developer redefinition of commonly used macros.
>
> To instrument functions implicitly, when
> the kernel is configured to support function tracing, the kernel build system adds [-pg](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-pg) to the flags used with
> the compiler. This causes the compiler to add code to
> the prologue of each function, which calls a special assembly routine called mcount. This compiler option is
> specifically intended to be used for profiling and tracing
> purposes.

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-entirely-copied-and-improperly-attributed-o/321326#321326)*