# C# ASP.NET VS 2010 Professional profiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am developing an ASP.NET application and I am looking to tune up some bottle-necks in my code's performance. I enabled tracing on my page, but it only gives a high-level overview of the page life-cycle and which parts of the page life-cycle are taking the longest to complete.

I would like to extend this and see specifically which of my functions are taking the longest to complete. I see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) that VS2010 Professional does not have native support for a profiler.

Am I out of luck? What should be my course of action here? Thanks.

Comment: [Check this out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118) Here's why [it works.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387895/if-profiler-is-not-the-answer-what-other-choices-do-we-have/4390868#4390868)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [JetBrains dotProfiler](http://jetbrains.com) or [Red Gate ANTS](http://redgate.com), which are both excellent profilers.