# how to profile code more accurately and precisely on windows vista?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, optimization, g++

Hey guys, I have a question.
how to profile code more accurately and precisely?
My OS is windows vista and my processor is Intel Centrino.

Right now I am compiling my c++ code using "-O0 -o" option on g++ and I am profiling using window's "QueryPerformanceCounter" and related APIs

accuracy and precision are two different things.
if you are shooting something, it hits the target rather than missing is called accurate.
And shooting many times, it hits same places rather than hitting many many different place is called precise.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's lots of discussion on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387895/if-profiler-is-not-the-answer-what-other-choices-do-we-have/4390868#4390868) If the reason for profiling is to discover ways to make the code faster, what helps you the most is to find them with certainty. Measuring the amount of time they cost with precision is much less important.

[Here's an example in another language and OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378), but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried AMD's CodeAnalyst tool? It's a free download and may be helpful.