# Profiling by line with Python 3

Tags: profiling, python-3.x

How can I do profiling by line in Python 3? The standard profilers have only function-level precision.

Comment: If you have the profiles of all of the functions, doesn't that mean that you have all of the lines???

Comment: @cwallenpoole: No it does not. But if you had the profile of all the lines, you would probably have the profile of all the functions.

Comment: Hi Matt. FWIW, I'm pretty sure we've discussed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387895/if-profiler-is-not-the-answer-what-other-choices-do-we-have/4390868#4390868) before. It gives you approximate cost and exact location of the heaviest lines, whether exclusive or inclusive.

Comment: Have you tried, CProfile or hotshot?

Comment: @cwallenpoole: No. But if the lines of a function are disjoint from any other function's lines as they are in Python, then having the profile of all lines means you can calculate the profile all functions. I'm not aware of cprofile fitting this criterion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While [line_profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) only works for Python 2.x, it doesn't seem too hard to make the necessary changes to get it to work with 3.x.

I've done this myself [here](https://bitbucket.org/mba105/line_profiler/). It's quick and dirty and pretty much untested, so use it at your peril, but it's possibly a start.

Comment: Nice! You answered just in time for me to see it :) 
Any chance of getting your 3.x update into the "main" version? Or better yet, get line_profiler into the Python stdlib...

Answer (score 5):

There's a nice Pull Request that implements Python 3 support very well

https://bitbucket.org/robertkern/line_profiler/pull-request/2/python-25-33-compatibility-using-a-single/

Answer (score 3):

As for the *line_profiler*, a recent working pull request is [here](https://bitbucket.org/robertkern/line_profiler/pull-request/2/python-26-33-compatibility-using-a-single/diff) waiting for an inclusion. The fork can be installed via:

```
pip install cython
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/kmike/line_profiler@7999f21#egg=line_profiler
```

It works for me at least on Python 3.4.1 with *IPython* magic functions.